# legend over the plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I don't want to have the legend over the plot as shown in Figure. I want it inside the figure box but not over the plot. Also, the number format of y-axis, i want to have it 0.001, 0.002, etc.

[image]

The code of my figure is

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{center}               
\begin{tikzpicture}          
\begin{axis}[xmin=0.09, ymin=0, xlabel={Froude number},ylabel={Resistance coefficient}, legend style={draw=none, legend columns=0}, width=10cm, height=7cm, legend pos=north west]

\addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] table [x=Fr, y=ct, col sep=comma] {model resistnace.csv};
\addlegendentry{$C_{T}$}

\addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] table [x=Fr, y=cf, col sep=comma] {model resistnace.csv};
\addlegendentry{$C_{F}$}

\addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] table [x=Fr, y=cr, col sep=comma] {model resistnace.csv};
\addlegendentry{$C_{R}$}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Resistance coefficients of ship model at full load default trim condition}
\label{resiscoef}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One note: don't use the `center` environment inside the `figure` environment: it adds extra unneeded vertical space. Just one `\centering` placed somewhere inside the `figure` environment will do the job better.

Since I didn't have your data, I made some "dummy" functions that have roughly the same behavior. You can do the same for future questions: it makes it easier/faster for others to help you.

I see that you already discovered the `legend pos` key, which solves most of these problems. But with your plots, all the corners are not good options. Looking in the manual (Section 4.9.5), we can find that the `legend pos` key is really just a set of shortcuts for

```
legend style={at={(<x>,<y>)},anchor=<name>}
```

So we can use

```
legend style={at={(1,0.5)},anchor=east},
```

to place the legend, anchored at its east edge, at the right side of (`x=1`) and midway up (`y=0.5`) the axis. You can adjust those values and the anchor to place the legend anywhere in the axis viewport.

Now, about the numbering: check out the manual, Section 4.13.1, where you'll find lots of common settings for this. In this case, we need

```
scaled y ticks=false,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},
```

which disables scaled ticks for the y-axis and sets fixed format with 3 digits displayed after the decimal separator.

Here's the complete code and output:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}          
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0.09, 
  ymin=0, 
  xlabel={Froude number},
  ylabel={Resistance coefficient}, 
  legend style={draw=none, legend columns=0}, 
  width=10cm, 
  height=7cm, 
  legend pos=north west,
  %%%% BEGIN STYLE CHANGES/ADDITIONS %%%
  domain=0.092:0.208, % just for the example
  legend style={at={(1,0.5)},anchor=east},
  scaled y ticks=false,
  yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},
]
  %%% DUMMY FUNCTIONS IN LIEU OF DATA %%%
  \addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] {5e-3-1e-3*x};
  \addlegendentry{$C_{T}$}
  \addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] {4.5e-3-3e-3*x};
  \addlegendentry{$C_{F}$}
  \addplot+ [mark=0,smooth] {7e-4+1e-3*x};
  \addlegendentry{$C_{R}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Can it be like excel legend ? inside the box but not over the plot. Is it possible ?

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam I tried to explain how you could move the legend around the axis box (by changing the `(1,0.5)` and `anchor=east` parts of the code). Do you want something other than that?

Comment: Thank you @paul
what about the domain. does it needs to be changed

Comment: I did it @paul
Thank you for your help. I put ymax=0.006 then changed (1,0.5) to (1,0.9).

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam the `domain` part is only there for the example, to limit the data plotted. It's not needed when you're plotting your actual data files.